# Refresh token returns invalid grant type

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to refresh the access token (based on https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Refresh+Token+Grant) obtained from wso2 identity server; the server returns an invalid grant type response

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Provided Authorization Grant is invalid"
}
```

The access token is obtained using the "authorization code" grant type with the openid scope.

I've turned on the logging on the server; however, I'm not able to determine the reason for the invalid grant type response. How can i get the WSO2 Identity Server to refresh my access token using the refresh token?

***Logs from the server:***

> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14 09:20:11,241] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Access Token
>   request received for Client ID CHao3ZYUVY6tRX4jJ82yzh4NVpka, User ID
>   null, Scope : [openid] and Grant Type : refresh_token
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14 09:20:11,241] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler}
>   -  Can authenticate with client ID and Secret. Client ID: CHao3ZYUVY6tRX4jJ82yzh4NVpka  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14
>   09:20:11,241] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler}
>   -  Grant type : refresh_token Strict client validation set to : null
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14 09:20:11,242] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client
>   credentials were fetched from the database.  TID: [-1234] []
>   [2016-03-14 09:20:11,242] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Successfully
>   authenticated the client with client id : CHao3ZYUVY6tRX4jJ82yzh4NVpka
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14 09:20:11,243] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client
>   credentials were added to the cache for client id :
>   CHao3ZYUVY6tRX4jJ82yzh4NVpka
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14 09:20:11,245] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.RefreshGrantHandler}
>   -  Invalid Refresh Token provided for Client with Client Id : CHao3ZYUVY6tRX4jJ82yzh4NVpka
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14 09:20:11,245] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Invalid
>   Grant provided by the client Id: CHao3ZYUVY6tRX4jJ82yzh4NVpka
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-14 09:20:11,246] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} - 
>   OAuth-Error-Code=invalid_grant client-id=CHao3ZYUVY6tRX4jJ82yzh4NVpka
>   grant-type=refresh_token scope=openid

Comment: Hi Hank. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @JonathanWilliams checkout my resent solution to this and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Jonathan, sorry for the delayed response. I've not found a viable solution for the device. However, if you have the session cookies (web applications) of the original authentication request, and pass these cookies during the refresh of the token, then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Question is old... Hopefully it can help someone else after this long ;).
I had the same issue. However, I resolved it by specifying the exact `refresh token`. It's worth noting that `refresh_token` is different from the `access token`. If you don't have/know your `refresh_token`, use this `curl` command to get it.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Authorization: Basic SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

response will be like this: 
`{
  "scope": "default",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 2604,
  "refresh_token": "7d6e9047d44a84e6bae7e80e3996182d",
  "access_token": "4255a34923eb464b6dc2983acffef4d8"
}`

then use that `refresh_token` in your `renew` token curl call.
more details on the 1st curl request [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Generating+Access+Tokens+with+User+Credentials+-+Password+Grant+Type)
Peace out .V.

Comment: i have indeed used the refresh token and not the access token to refresh the call. Its worth noting that the grant type you have used is the password grant where in you must have the client credentials (user name and password). My use case is using the grant type 'authorization' code and actual authentication server could be WSO2 Identity Server, Facebook, Twitter or any third party system that supports tokens (OpenID/OAuth2)